# How to make PL/Python tracebacks more verbose?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

Currently in case of error I have such traceback in `psql` for PL/Python procedure, that imports Python module and calls some function from it:

```
ERROR:  AssertionError: 
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains", line 6, in <module>
    TimeIntervalSet.from_json(timeintervalset))
  PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains", line 209, in __contains__
  PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains", line 106, in _walk
  PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains", line 41, in _evaluate
  PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains", line 200, in callback
  PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains", line 91, in __contains__
PL/Python function "tempo_timeintervalset_contains"
```

I've tried to set `log_error_verbosity = verbose` in `postgresql.conf` and set this environment variables `PYTHONVERBOSE=1 PYTHONDEBUG=1`. Nothing helped.

Who knows, how to actually set it to be more verbose if it's possible at all?

Comment: Looks pretty verbose. What're you expecting?

Comment: @CraigRinger Regular Python traceback looks like this: https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/b27d5888b0157c245e68

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old,  but I find this works well.

```
create function python_version()
returns text
language plpythonu
as $$

import sys
import traceback

try:
    return sys.version
except:
    error = sys.exc_info()[0]
    details = traceback.format_exc()
    plpy.error('%s: %s' % ( error, details ) )
$$;
```